# Loading properties file gives null

Tags: java, properties, classpath, filenotfoundexception

In the `main()` class i put a code:

```
App.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("Repo-Offer.properties")
```

the result is `null`

The property file resides in:

```
Project/src/main/resources/properties/Repo-Offer.properties
```

I was trying to load properties like this:

```
private Properties getPropertiesFromClasspath(String propFileName) throws IOException {
    // loading xmlProfileGen.properties from the classpath
    Properties props = new Properties();
    InputStream inputStream = this.getClass().getClassLoader()
        .getResourceAsStream(propFileName);

    if (inputStream == null) {
        throw new FileNotFoundException("property file '" + propFileName
            + "' not found in the classpath");
    }

    props.load(inputStream);

    return props;
}
```

but because of that null it says

```
  Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: Repo-Offer.properties
```

How to use the properties files from:
    Project/src/main/resources/properties/Repo-Offer.properties 
while the source is in

```
Project/src/main/java/com/...
```

?
**EDIT
It is Maven project.**

Comment: Try to load `getResourceAsStream("properties/Repo-Offer.properties")`. Does it work?

Comment: Is this actually a Maven project? How are you creating and running the final artifact?

Comment: @Dave Newton Yes it is maven project. Run it from Eclipse GUI interface.

Comment: @LaurentG se my answer below

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are using Maven, the properties file will land in `/properties/Repo-Offer.properties`, so use that as file path.
Have a look in `target/classes` to verify the proper path.

Comment: For: `System.out.println(App.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/properties/Repo-Offer.properties")` I keep getting the:null

Comment: @mCs What about without the leading `/`?

Comment: @Dave Newton Yes, that was the case. Thank you the leading `/`